# Trigger Datatable print from Custom Print Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have a Datatable in Bootstrap3 Framework. I would like to give an option to print the datatable through a Print button.

Here is the jquery instantiation of my datatable

> $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
>           'buttons': ['excel', 'pdf', 'print']      });

However, the button for print doesnt fit into my theme and would like to trigger the datatable print function through a custom print button. Any idea how this can be achieved ?

Reference : [Documentation for Datatable Print](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export)

Answer (score 2):

You should add custom print button event like this:

**Button**

```
<button id="btnPrint">Custom Print Button</button>
```

**JS**

```
/* custom button event print */
$(document).on('click', '#btnPrint', function(){
   $(".buttons-print")[0].click(); //trigger the click event
});
```

You can see live demo here:  https://output.jsbin.com/cozadek

https://jsbin.com/cozadek/13/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you so much, really helped. Appreciate all the help

Comment: Does not work in bootstrap 4, Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Comment: @TechPotter I'm guessing your problem was related to the actual buttons not being on the page.  I currently looking for a solution to this myself, because obviously a custom button isn't that great if you still have to have the old ones.

Comment: @TechPotter you can add actual button, and hide it.